# ZBar remove info button (ios 6)

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk, zbar

How to I remove the information button from the toolbar at the bottom screen (reader screen).I have tried the using the overlay method but it didn't work. Hope someone would save me. Thanks

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];
    reader.readerDelegate =self;
    reader.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    reader.showsCameraControls=YES;
    // Define button title color when disabled (Grey)
    [btnFindMe setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [self activateScan];

}




-(void) activateScan
{

    ZBarReaderViewController *reader  = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
    [reader.scanner setSymbology: 0
                          config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                              to: 0];
    [reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_QRCODE
                          config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                              to: 1];
    reader.readerView.zoom = 1;
    reader.showsZBarControls=FALSE;
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0)];
     overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,510.0,320.0,54.0)];
     UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                     target:self                                     action:@selector(closeScanner)];
     toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton,nil];

    [overlay addSubview:toolbar];
    reader.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [self presentModalViewController: reader  animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating new `UIView` & apply it to `cameraOverlayView` property of `ZBarReaderViewController`'s object `codeReader`.

It's actually recommended from ZBar official docs.

```
self.codeReader.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.codeReader.showsZBarControls = NO;
[self.codeReader setCameraOverlayView:self.viewCancelButtonQRCodeReader];
```

[Here's the screenshot of `UIView` that i added. It has background color as `clearColor`.]

[image: UIView for camera overlay]